# Typescript: this inside parameters of arrow function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm familiar with the behaviour of `this` inside an arrow function in typescript (or at least I thought so). 
However today I stumbled across a `this` being used in the arguments list of an arrow function (this is from the type definitions of the alexa-sdk):

```
export interface Handlers<T> {
    [intent: string]: (this: Handler<T>) => void;
}
```

What does this actually mean and how would I implement this?

```
let handlers: Handlers<IntentRequest> = {
    "MyIntent" = ???
}
```

I know that I can do something like:

```
let handlers: Handlers<IntentRequest> = {
        "MyIntent" = function() {
           let self: Alexa.Handler<IntentRequest> = this;
        }
}
```

but is there a more elegant solution without the self/this assignment with a arrow function?

Comment: You should check `this parameters` section here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer versions of typescript you can specify the type of this as a pseudo paramter to the function

```
let handlers: Handlers<IntentRequest> = {
    "MyIntent": function (this: Handlers<IntentRequest> /* , realParam: string */) {
       // this will have the type Handlers<IntentRequest>
    }
}
```